# The submit50 for cs50 is not working 2021 DEC

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, cs50

I am using VSC. Here is the output of the clone command, clone which is not working:

```bash
$ cd ubuntu/labs/lab8
ubuntu/labs/lab8/ $ submit50 cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia
Preparing files ...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa': 
fatal: remote error: 
  classroom50/cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia is not a valid repository name
  Visit https://support.github.com/ for help
Failed to clone "git@github.com:/classroom50/cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia".
ubuntu/labs/lab8/ $
```

Why the clone is failing?

Comment: Command line:
$ cd ubuntu/labs/lab8
ubuntu/labs/lab8/ $ submit50 cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia
Preparing files ...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa': 
fatal: remote error: 
  classroom50/cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia is not a valid repository name
  Visit https://support.github.com/ for help
Failed to clone "git@github.com:/classroom50/cs50/labs/2021/x/trivia".
ubuntu/labs/lab8/ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clone is for a repository, not a folder inside the repository.

Check what "`submit50`" does, and what is the remote URL you are using.

```
git remote -v
```

The git clone should use an URL like:

```
git@github.com:<UserName>/<RepoName>
             ^^^ (no / there)
```

Answer (score 0):

The clone is failing because in 2021, submit50 doesn't work for Visual Studio Code. Moderates from CS50's discord server said so.